# Is there file manager like windows explorer with features described below

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager

[image: image 1]

1. When in compact view the file names must be shown full, i.e. without dot dot dot at the end, so the columns width must scale to that file names in it.
2. Scrolling must scroll exactly to the next column, and not to somewhere between two columns or 1/3 column. It must scroll the way that next column folder or files names appears at the left border of the work window, just like the windows explorer.

Please help me find that file manager! Thank you

Comment: Dolphin does the first. I do not understand the second.

Comment: Thunar and PCManFM also do 1. For point 2: also unclear to me: not specific enough.

Comment: Ok, if i have many folders in directory and the view mode is compact - then i'm trying to scroll folders to the right using the mouse wheel down the folders are scrolling like web browser page - smoothly - and the result of scrolling is half of the column folders name could be overscrolled i.e. not visible. In windows exlorer if i scroll in same situation the folders column names to the left is always fully visible and you could scroll and scroll by mouse wheel - it is always that directory view is looks like - and scroll is not smooth - its like from point to point from one column to another